# Phonegap ChildBrowser Blackberry Plugin:Cannot call method 'showWebPage' of undefined

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-plugins, cordova-2.0.0

I keep getting this error in Chrome Developer Tools when trying to make use of the ChildBrowser plugin for blackberry: TypeError: Cannot call method 'showWebPage' of undefined

In firebug I get :TypeError: cordova.exec is not a function

"showWebPage", [url, options ]);

Here are my codes

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Share QR</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">      
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />

  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="childbrowser.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
  <script src="details.js"></script>
</head>

<body id="main" >
  <div data-role="page" id="home" data-position="fixed">

      <div data-role="header"> 
    <h1>Home</h1> 
 </div>

<div data-role="content">
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true"  id="listItem"></ul>     

    </div>

    <div data-role="footer">
      <div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#home" data-icon="grid">Feeds</a></li>
        <li><a href="#videos" data-icon="plus">Videos</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- /navbar -->
    </div>
 </div>

  <div data-role="page" id="videos" data-position="fixed" data-add-back-btn="true">

      <div data-role="header"> 
    <h1>Home</h1> 
 </div>

<div data-role="content">
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true"  id="listItemvid"></ul>     

    </div>

    <div data-role="footer">
      <div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#home" data-icon="grid">Feeds</a></li>
        <li><a href="#videos" data-icon="plus">Videos</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- /navbar -->
    </div>
 </div>



 </body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
var serviceURL = 'http://localhost/feeds/services/';

  function onDeviceReady() {
        // Now safe to use the PhoneGap API
        alert("Ready");
    }

 $(document).bind('pageinit', function(){
       $('#listItem li').remove();
      document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    $.getJSON(serviceURL + 'getdata.php', function(data){
    $.each(data, function(index, value){
    var output = '';
    output += '<li><a href="details.html?id=' + value.id + '"><img src="pics/' + value.id + '.jpg"/>' + value.name + '</a></li>';
    $("#listItem").append(output).listview("refresh");
       });
        });
   });




$('#videos').live('pageshow', function(event) {
     $('#listItemvid li').remove();
    $.getJSON(serviceURL + 'getdata.php', function(data){
    $.each(data, function(index, value){
    var output = '';
    output += '<li><img src="pics/' + value.id + '.jpg"/>' + value.name + '</a></li>';
    $("#listItemvid").append(output).listview("refresh");
       });
    });
});

 $('#listItemvid').live('vclick', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
   // alert("i'm running!");
   if(window.cordova){
       alert("loaded");
   var cb = window.plugins.childBrowser;
   cb.showWebPage('http://www.google.com',
                                        { showLocationBar: true });}

   else{ 
   alert("Not Available");
   }
});

plugin.xml
<plugins>
  <plugin name="App"            value="org.apache.cordova.app.App"/>
  <plugin name="Device"         value="org.apache.cordova.device.Device"/>
  <plugin name="Camera"         value="org.apache.cordova.camera.Camera"/>
  <plugin name="NetworkStatus"  value="org.apache.cordova.network.Network"/>
  <plugin name="Notification"   value="org.apache.cordova.notification.Notification"/>
  <plugin name="Accelerometer"  value="org.apache.cordova.accelerometer.Accelerometer"/>
  <plugin name="Geolocation"    value="org.apache.cordova.geolocation.Geolocation"/>
  <plugin name="File"           value="org.apache.cordova.file.FileManager"/>
  <plugin name="FileTransfer"   value="org.apache.cordova.http.FileTransfer"/>
  <plugin name="Contacts"       value="org.apache.cordova.pim.Contact"/>
  <plugin name="Capture"        value="org.apache.cordova.capture.MediaCapture"/>
  <plugin name="Battery"        value="org.apache.cordova.battery.Battery"/>
  <plugin name="Media"          value="org.apache.cordova.media.Media"/>
  <plugin name="ChildBrowser" value="org.apache.cordova.plugins.childbrowser.ChildBrowser"/>
</plugins>

config.xml
I included 
<gap:plugin name="ChildBrowser" src="org.apache.cordova.plugins.childbrowser.ChildBrowser" version="~3"  />
```

I have search google for help but everybody seem to have the issue reolved but their steps  didnot resolve my issue.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to use the phonegap plugin:childbrowser, I actually obeserved dat the error is coming frm wen d childBrowser.js class is trying to call the replica in d native java childBrowser.java class.

Answer (score 0):

@Kehinde Kolexinfos Kolade: Hey you can not use the childbrowser for desktop browser. It can be used for mobile apps. The child browser allows you to display external web pages within your Cordova application in either a custom browser field or in the device's builtin browser.